# Publishing a component doesn't publish the page?

Tags: tridion

When I publish a component in SDL Tridion, the page it's used on doesn't always publish. What conditions are needed in order to publish a component and have its page get published as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In either the SiteEdit or Content Manager Explorer (CME) interface, content editors can publish components or pages.

Publishing components will *also* publish the pages they are used on only if those pages are *already published* for the given publication target.

This may cause confusion especially with the page-focused SiteEdit (SDL Tridion inline editor) interface when selecting and publishing components instead of the entire page.

When in doubt, publish the page at least once to the appropriate publication target. Once the page is published, you can publish either the component or the page to that target to make updates.

Comment: If dig a bit deeper, publishing component will only publish page that was published before if the component is part of a static component presentation. Otherwise, just dynamic component presentation will be published

Comment: Good point. Publishing a page that has a dynamic component presentation (set on the CT) will also publish the DCPs on it, whereas yes publishing the DCP won't publish the page regardless if the page is out there or not.